# Infinite series for arctan of x

Tags: sequences-and-series

this is a bit of a vague question so I won't be too surprised if I get vague responses.

$$\tan^{-1}(x) = x - (x^3 / 3) + (x^5 / 5) - (x^7 / 7) + \cdots $$ ad infinitum

I'm using this, where $x = (\sqrt{2} - 1)$ to calculate $\pi$, as $\pi = 8  \tan^{-1}(x)$

I have never really learnt about infinite series before, and obviously when I translate this into a python code, I can't use a range from $(0, \infty)$.

So, my question is this; How do I/can I represent this idea in the form of a geometric series or is that the wrong way of going about it?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that it is not a geometric series, so you cannot turn it into a nice closed-form expression. You can get approximations for $\pi$ by taking the first $N$ terms for some choice of $N$.

Comment: So it's acceptable to take an infinite series and just evaluate n number of terms - as long as you keep in mind you get only an approximation with accuracy dependent on number of terms evaluated.

Comment: What $ x = (\sqrt{2} - 1)$ has to do?

Comment: That comes from saying tan(pi/8) = x, then substituting back into the trig identity to get x^2 + 2x - 1. Completing the square gives you sqrt(2) - 1

Comment: @Jacobadtr: Indeed. The accuracy depends on how many terms you use, but also on how fast the series converges to the right value. For instance, a famous fast-converging series to compute $\pi$ is [$\pi = 16 \arctan(1/5) - 4 \arctan(1/239)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi).

Comment: Perhaps I will have a look at that next if it's not beyond me.

My main goal is to write this bit of code that converges faster than my previous bit that used the leibniz series. Apparently the leibniz series is very slow so i'll enjoy comparing the two. Is there a way to describe how much faster than something else, something converges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only going to get an approximation good to some number of decimal places.  If you use $N$ terms in the series, then the error is approximately the magnitude of the $N+1$th term.  The question you must ask yourself is, if I want $M$ decimal places of accuracy, then how big must $N$ be?

Example: say you want $M=6$ places of accuracy.  Then

$$\frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)^{2 N+1}}{2 N+1} < 10^{-6}$$

By trial and error, I get $N=6$.  That means you only need $6$ terms in the series to get that level of accuracy.

Comment: I concur with $ \ N = 6 \ $ satisfying the inequality, so the series can stop with the $ \ N = 5 \ $ term (giving an exponent of 11).  But using this general term, the first term in the arctangent Taylor polynomial corresponds to $ \ N = 0 \ $ , so you would need 6 terms.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: you are right - thanks.

Comment: I usually find it easier just to state the value of the index at which to terminate.  (The _number_ of terms required for a series at a specified precision is the subject of numerous "nasty little" multiple-choice questions I have seen on exams.)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to **truncate** at some point. For this kind of *alternating series* (terms alternate in sign, decrease in absolute value, and have limit $0$) the truncation error is $\lt$ the first "neglected" term.

**Remark:** Note that $\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{3}=\tan^{-1}1 =\frac{\pi}{4}$. This may be a more pleasant way to approximate $\pi$ than stuff involving $\sqrt{2}$. There are many such "Machin-like" formulas.

Comment: I think what you're talking about there is the leibniz series? I have actually written a piece of code that evaluates that for some range of n. It converges very slowly though, for (0, 500000) I get about 5 significant figures correct.

The way I am trying now is supposed to converge faster, and is really just practice in math and coding for me - it's not of practical use.

Comment: I am definitely not talking about the Leibniz series, which in unmodified form is computationally hopeless. I am taking about taking **two** series, one for $\tan^{-1}(1/2)$, the other for $\tan^{-1}(1/3)$, and adding suitably truncated versions. Apart from differences of detail (what was actually used was usually $4\tan^{-1}(1/5)+\tan^{-1}(1/239)$) this is how high precision computations were done from the $18$-th century to the $20$-th. Look in Wikipedia for Machin-like formulas. To be concrete, the series used would be the one you quote, except we would be adding two of them.